# Why do I get "System.Data.MetadataException: 'Unable to load the specified metadata resource.'" error when using EF6 connectionString from code?

Tags: sql-server, wcf, entity-framework-6

I know there are a number of questions/answers having to do with this error, and I apologize for being repetitive, but I have not seen any so far that deal with the error occurring from program code while trying to Open() the entity connection.

I have a `VS2017 C# Windows Forms` solution, `.NET 4.5.2`, with `WCF` Service Application using  `Entity Framework 6.2`, that includes a logic layer, BDO layer and data layer. My entity context was created `database-first`.

My service is `self-hosted` in my UI client project's `Program.cs` file. The transport is `net.pipe` since both the client and services are on the same computer.

My database is remote, version `SQL Server 2016 (130)`, requiring user id and password, and its connection string works great when defined in the `App.config` for my UI client project.

But, I am currently trying to remove the connection string from `App.config` and **to code it in the `Program.cs` `Main()` method** for security purposes.

I am using `SqlConnectionStringBuilder` and `EntityConnectionStringBuilder` to build the entity connection string "provider" and "metadata" pieces, and I can build the same connection string in my `Program.cs` code as I'm using in `App.config`.

But, when my code opens the entity connection, I get an error:

> System.Data.MetadataException: **`Unable to load the specified metadata resource.`**

Here is my `App.config` `connectionString` section which works fine:

```
<connectionStrings>
    <add name="MyDBEntities" 
         connectionString="metadata=res://*/MyDB.csdl|res://*/MyDB.ssdl|res://*/MyDB.msl;provider=System.Data.SqlClient;provider connection string=&quot;data source=myremotewebsite.com;initial catalog=MyDB;persist security info=True;user id=theUserID;password=thePassword;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;App=EntityFramework&quot;" 
         providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" />
</connectionStrings>
```

And here is my C# code from `Program.cs` in UI client project:

```
using System.ServiceModel;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Data.EntityClient;

namespace myUICLient
{
    static class Program
    {
        public static ServiceHost hostMyService;

        // Specify the provider name, server and database.
        public static string sqlProvider = "System.Data.SqlClient"; 
        public static string serverName = "myremotewebsite.com";
        public static string databaseName = "MyDB";
        public static string userID = "theUserID";
        public static string passWord = "thePassword";
        public static string App = "EntityFramework";
        public static string providerString;
    
        public static SqlConnectionStringBuilder sqlBuilder = new SqlConnectionStringBuilder();
        public static EntityConnectionStringBuilder entityBuilder = new EntityConnectionStringBuilder();

        public static EntityConnection MyDBEntities;   

        [STAThread]
        static void Main()
        {
            hostMyService = new ServiceHost(typeof(prjMyServiceApplication.MyService),
                                   new Uri("net.pipe://localhost/prjUICLient/MyService.svc"));
            hostMyService.Open();

            // Set the properties for the data source.
            sqlBuilder.DataSource = serverName;
            sqlBuilder.InitialCatalog = databaseName;
            sqlBuilder.UserID = userID;
            sqlBuilder.Password = passWord;
            sqlBuilder.IntegratedSecurity = false;
            sqlBuilder.PersistSecurityInfo = true;
            sqlBuilder.MultipleActiveResultSets = true;
            sqlBuilder.ApplicationName = App;

            // Build the SqlConnection connection string.
            providerString = sqlBuilder.ToString();

            // Set the provider name.
            entityBuilder.Provider = sqlProvider;  
        
            // Set the Metadata location.
            entityBuilder.Metadata = @"res://*/MyDB.csdl|res://*/MyDB.ssdl|res://*/MyDB.msl";

            // Set the provider-specific connection string.
            entityBuilder.ProviderConnectionString = providerString;

            using (MyDBEntities = new EntityConnection(entityBuilder.ToString()))
            {
                MyDBEntities.Open(); // gets the error here!

                Application.EnableVisualStyles();
                Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);
                Application.Run(new myWinForm());

                hostMyService.Close();

                MyDBEntities.Close();
           }
       }
   }
}
```

When the code errors out, I can view the metadata portion of connection string in the error data, and also see a "Server Version" error:

```
       "metadata=res://*/MyDB.csdl|
        res://*/MyDB.ssdl|
        res://*/MyDB.msl;
        provider=System.Data.SqlClient;provider connection string=\"Data Source=myremotewebsite.com;
        Initial Catalog=MyDB;Integrated Security=False;Persist Security Info=True;
        User ID=MyUserID;Password=MyPassword;
        MultipleActiveResultSets=True;Application Name=EntityFramework\""
```

> MyDBEntities.ServerVersion = 'MyDBEntities.ServerVersion' threw an exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException'

When I comment out the Open() statement in Main() and run again, I get the following error from the DAL layer when the Service call is made:

> The underlying provider failed on Open

Thanks for any help or advice you have to offer.

`Update 2021.03.04` after finding the `folder location` of the `model` files
in my data layer project under this path:

> prjDAL
> . obj . Release . edmxResourcesToEmbed
> .  MyDB.csdl, MyDB.msl, MyDB.ssdl

I `changed my metadata string` to the following:

```
      entityBuilder.Metadata = @"res://prjDAL.dll/MyDB.csdl|
                                 res://prjDAL.dll/MyDB.ssdl|
                                 res://prjDAL.dll/MyDB.msl";
```

And reran, got this `new error:`

> System.IO.FileNotFoundException: **'Unable to resolve assembly `prjDAL.dll`**.

I have read the article in the recommended link and what I have learned so far is that the "Resource" and the "Model" are two different things.  The examples in the linked article look like MVC examples where the connection string is in the App.config file.  I'm not using MVC, but .NET 4.5.2 n-Tier winforms design, and `I don't have a problem when I use the connection string in the App.config` file.  My problem comes when trying to create the connection string `in code`, and trying to `open the EntityConnection` object.

Here are more options I have tried:
This metadata:

```
  entityBuilder.Metadata = @"res://prjDAL.dll/resources.MyDB.csdl|
                             res://prjDAL.dll/resources.MyDB.ssdl|
                             res://prjDAL.dll/resources.MyDB.msl";
```

Gets this error:

> System.IO.FileNotFoundException: `Unable to resolve assembly 'prjDAL.dll'.`

And this metadata:

```
  entityBuilder.Metadata=
      @"res://prjUICLient/bin/prjDAL.dll/
              prjUICLient.Resources.MyDB.csdl|

        res://prjUICLient/bin/prjDAL.dll/
              prjUICLient.Resources.MyDB.ssdl|

        res://prjUICLient/bin/prjDAL.dll/
              prjUICLient.Resources.MyDB.msl";
```

Gets this error:

> System.Data.MetadataException: `The specified metadata path is not valid.`
> A valid path must be either an existing directory,
> an existing file with extension '.csdl', '.ssdl', or '.msl',
> or a URI that identifies an embedded resource.

Tried again pointing metadata to assembly in DAL layer:

```
  entityBuilder.Metadata = @"res://prjDAL/obj/Release/prjDAL.dll/
                           prjDAL.obj.release.edmxResourcesToEmbed.MyDB.csdl|
                res://prjDAL/obj/Release/prjDAL.dll/
                           prjDAL.obj.release.edmxResourcesToEmbed.MyDB.ssdl|
                res://prjDAL/obj/Release/prjDAL.dll/                                                   
                           prjDAL.obj.release.edmxResourcesToEmbed.MyDB.msl";
```

> System.Data.MetadataException: `The specified metadata path is not valid.`
> A valid path must be either an existing directory,
> an existing file with extension '.csdl', '.ssdl', or '.msl',
> or a URI that identifies an embedded resource.

**Has anyone made this Entity connection string conversion from App.config to code in a .NET 4.5.2 WinForms multi-tiered application?**

`Do I need to upgrade my application to .NET Standard or .NET CORE?`

Comment: You can try this link:https://www.craigstuntz.com/posts/2010-08-13-troubleshooting-entity-framework-connection-strings.html

Comment: Thanks @Theobald Du.  I found the Model files in my DAL layer project. I'm working on adding in the correct assembly name and the model names.

Comment: @Theobald Du :   can't seem to make this work no matter what I try, maybe upgrading to Core or .NET Standard would help.  May do that in a later version.  I'll stay with what I have in this version, which is using the App.config - it works great, but I would rather not have to deploy the App.config file with username/password in it.  Is there a way to deploy the App.config without the username/password in the connection string?

Comment: You can try to add the permissions of the current user to your database file. I used to be unable to access the database due to permission issues.

Comment: Thanks @Theobald Du - my database is SQL Server 2016 on a Remote website, so as long as I know the username/pwd combo in my ConnectionString, I should be able to connect to the database with no issues.  There is no problem connecting when using the connectionstring is in the App.config file.  I think I'll try converting my .NET Framework to 4.7 and trying again.